# CSS Menu not aligning properly

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

Im designing a mobile app in jquery mobile. Im trying design a responsive menu but problem is when my menu content is more than 1 line its acting weird. here is a screenshot of what I want and what I got.

[image]

here is my stylesheet

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="about.html"><img src="images/icon1.png" border="0" alt="" title="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html"><img src="images/icon2.png" border="0" alt="" title="">My blog &amp; Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html"><img src="images/icon3.png" border="0" alt="" title="">Photos</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
 menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 25px;
    }
    .menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 0px 6px 5px 6px;
    background: url(images/icon_bg.png) no-repeat center top;
    }
    .menu ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #302f2f;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #dcdcdc;
    }
    .menu ul li a img {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    }
```

here us jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xr8kL/

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle or live link to the issue.

Comment: @NathanLee updated with jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xr8kL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Just add a `vertical-align:top;` to `.menu ul li`

**For Instance,**

```
.menu ul li {
    background: url("images/icon_bg.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 125px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 6px 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 85px;
}
```

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr8kL/1/)**

Comment: o boy! you are awesome indeed! thanks a bunch Nathan. you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the jquery mobile grid layouts instead of trying to define the layout by your own css? Here is what I mean:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/content/content-grids.html

There is also a guide how to make these grids responsive

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/content/content-grids-responsive.html

Comment: grid is not working for me because I want each grid will adjust with screen width. so sometimes there will be 2 menu/3 menus etc. Im not sure how to do that in grid.